# Java Linked List remove object method

Tags: java, linked-list

I want to remove the element if it is present in a linkedlist while iterating over an array of numbers

```
for(int num : numbers)
{
   if(l.contains(num))
   {
      l.remove(num);
   }
}
```

However, it is trying to remove element at index num, instead of looking for num in the linked list.

The javadoc has this method

```
remove(Object o)
Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present.
```

How to use it?

Comment: Use `l.remove(new Integer(num));`

Comment: Also, don't use a `for each`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. 
So is it because if we use a primitive type, it takes it for index? So we have wrap it as object?

Comment: is `l` your linked list?  how do you initialie it?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar May I know why?

Comment: @ZouZou Use `l.remove(Integer.valueOf(num))`, not `new Integer(num)`.

Comment: @SamIam 

LinkedList<Integer> l=new LinkedList<Integer>();

Comment: @user2133404 `foreach` loops use an iterator to walk over the list, and altering the list while iterating over it invalidates the iterator.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this instead

```
for(Integer num : numbers)
    l.remove(num); // remove if present
```

This avoids the confusion with List.remove(int index) *called if you pass it an int* and List.remove(Object) *called if you pass it an object like Integer* and avoids scanning the list twice if the element is present.

Comment: @AJMansfield and what's the problem?

Comment: @user503413 actually now that I think some more, that isn't really a problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

You should box it in an `Integer` like this:

`l.remove(Integer.valueOf(num));`

or iterate over `Integer` objects instead of `int`s.

Answer (score 1):

I would instead just do this:

```
l.removeAll(Arrays.asList(numbers));
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call `remove(Object)`: invocation of `remove(num)` is not matching with the function with signature `remove(Object o)` where the function parameter is of reference type. instead it matches with `remove(int index)`.

Hence, invoking `remove(Integer.valueOf(num))` will work as it will pass a reference type.